# When test is runing to watch in parallel if specific element exist

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I need some help, can I somehow on every webdriver action (click() or loading page)  see if specific element is visible. I am working on a project, if on a  site appears any error, this element `<a style="color:#FFF;" href="#debug-plugin-error">` is visible and test must fail.

I dont want on every event/action to add some method that will validate this situation, maybe junit has some rule?! Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out EventFiringWebDriver which may help,

http://onlineseleniumtraining.com/how-to-working-with-listeners-in-selenium-webdriver/